# Picture Web Part Proerties customization

Tags: web-part, picture-library

I have a requirement to develop a picture web part that will gather pictures from various places in site collection and show the slideshow.

Custom Properties that needed are as follows:

1. There will be a dropdown where user can select a number from 1-10.
2. Depending on the number choosen dynamically that many textboxes needs to be generated so that user can put the links there. Also he should be able to set the sequence in which each image will be displayed using a dropdown next to each of the textbox.

Since i could not find any thing similar implemented in the net any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do a lot with web part properties, in most cases I think it is best to manage the configuration of that sort of system using a SharePoint list.  The properties are easily configured there and then easily read into the custom web part.